# debian: upgrade from etch to lenny fails

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, upgrade

The error message is:

```
 error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/debianutils_2.30_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite `/usr/sbin/add-shell', which is also in package passwd
```

How can I solve this problem? 
I'm doing

```
aptitude safe-upgrade
```

ouptput of dpkg -S add-shell:

```
passwd: /usr/sbin/add-shell
```

Comment: Did you try aptitude install passwd and then aptitude safe-upgrade?

Comment: Strange thing is that the mentioned add-shell file is in debianutils in both Etch and Lenny. Could you tell us what the output is of dpkg -S add-shell?

Comment: @lg: gives me the same error when trying aptitude install passwd :-/

Comment: @Jasper: Output has been added to the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: first upgrade from unstable etch to stable etch, then from etch to lenny.

It looks like you didn't have an up-to-date etch installation, according to the discussion for [bug #458452](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=458452). Upgrades are supported from one stable release to the next, and between successive states of an unstable release (including its final stable state), but not always for more complex cases. To upgrade to a stable etch even though it's disappeared from Debian mirrors, get it from `archive.debian.org`.

If `aptitude` is refusing to do anything until you repair the problem manually, you can run `dpkg --force-overwrite -i /var/cache/apt/archives/debianutils_2.30_i386.deb`. However going via etch would be a better idea (and you wouldn't have this problem, because the `debianutils` package from etch declares dependencues that cause `passwd` to be upgraded first).

Note that when upgrading to a new release, you typically need `full-upgrade` rather than `safe-upgrade`.

Comment: Mispelling? full-upgrade -> dist-upgrade

Comment: I had upgraded to archive.debian.org/ etch main before calling aptitude safe-upgrade. I've been following the official upgrade guide (that's why I put the safe-upgrade first, the dist-upgrade will follow later on)

Comment: @yas4891: what version of `passwd` and `debianutils` do you currently have? This error shouldn't have happened if you already had a stable etch system.

Comment: @lg: `full-upgrade` and `safe-upgrade` are synonyms of `dist-upgrade` and `upgrade` respectively.

Comment: @Gilles: Currently running through an aptitude upgrade with the legacy (etch) servers. He's doing quite a lot at the moment. So maybe I was wrong and didn't correctly upgrade my system. Sorry for that false information. I'll keep you posted whether it worked

Comment: Ok... /etc/debian_version now prints 5.0.5 So this worked! Thanks a lot!